# How can I play a file from 45 sec mark to the 51 sec mark?

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

Given a m4a file...  how can I play a file from 45 sec mark to the 51 sec mark?

I only want to play 6 seconds of that file, and not wait 45 seconds to hear it play.  thx

Here is how I am playing the whole file:

```
NSURL *soundFileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"abc" withExtension:@"m4a"];

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
player.numberOfLoops = 1; 

[player play];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From Documentation:**

```
- (BOOL)playAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
```

> Plays a sound asynchronously, starting at a specified point in the
>   audio output device’s timeline.

For example, to start playback three seconds into the future from the time you call this method, use code like this:

```
NSTimeInterval playbackDelay = 3.0;              
[myAudioPlayer playAtTime: myAudioPlayer.deviceCurrentTime + playbackDelay];
```

After 6 seconds, you can stop the audio player. You can either compare the audioplayer current time to 51secs, or you can have your own timer.

```
if(myAudioPlayer.currentTime >= 51{
    [myAudioPlayer stop];
 }
```

Comment: To stop this, you are saying I must run my own thread to keep track of the time and then "stop" the player?

Comment: I meant to say, once the player is started, you can either do something like if(player.currentTime==51) { [player stop] } else, start an nstimer after u start the player, and make this nstimer call player stop after 6 seconds.

Comment: So I can write code like the following:(one line after the other) ?

[player play]; 
if(player.currentDeviceTime==51) { [player stop] }

Comment: had to do (negative) or it waited 3 seconds to play:  NSTimeInterval playbackDelay = -3.0; and to stop it, I did: sleep(6); [myAudioPlayer stop];  thx